# Convert character dates with NA into date format - Something Strange?

Tags: r, date, datetime

As I can not share my data due to restriction . Please try to provide solution using the information below
I have a dataframe called data. There are variable which I want to convert into date and time format.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
data$Call_TimeStamp = as.POSIXct(paste(data$Local_call_Date, data$Local_call_Time.y), format= "%Y-%m-%d% %H:%M:%S", tz = 'GMT')



str(data$Call_TimeStamp)
   POSIXct[1:66288], format: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

But When I run query on another variables of the same dataset having the same date and time format it run perfectly , the only difference is those variables don't have NA in it as a character.

```
 data$Sent_TimeStamp=as.POSIXct(paste(data$Local_Sent_Date.x, data$Local_Sent_Time.x), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = 'GMT')
```

Comment: You have misplaced the `)` for your `paste` command. It should be `paste(data$Local_call_Date, data$Local_call_Time.y), "%Y-...`

Comment: For future reference remember that in the R tag you must share data by reproducible means such as `dput()` not screenshots.

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks for paying attention. Even after correcting the syntax it is giving NA . Please help

Comment: @Benjamin Please help

Answer (score 1):

Two things, one good, one (likely) bad:

- your data is in a sane format as far as the time string goes: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) -- this makes parsing easier
- your data is very likely in factor form and you forgot the required `as.character()`.

Now, the recently-release [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) package helps with both.  Here is one example from the webpage / [GH README.md](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime):

```
R> ## factor
R> anytime(as.factor(20160101 + 0:2))
[1] "2016-01-01 CST" "2016-01-02 CST" "2016-01-03 CST"
```

It will also parse with dates and time, with or without factor representation and still not require a format:

```
R> anytime("2016-01-02 03:04:05.678")
[1] "2016-01-02 03:04:05.677 CST"
R> anytime(as.factor("2016-01-02 03:04:05.678"))
[1] "2016-01-02 03:04:05.677 CST"
R>
```

You can install [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) directly from CRAN.

Comment: Thanks. Does anytime work when there is NA in a character ?. I am getting an error as : Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : Inadmissable input:

Comment: No, not currently.  How could one parse sensible information out of a `NA` without using magic or a time machine?

Comment: Dear anonymous user110244: I think you misunderstand what StackOverflow is for, and how it operates.

Comment: What I want is that the function just leaves the NA wherever they are in a character vector and convert other character dates into a date time format .

Comment: That is a (very basic) two-step:  `ind <- which( ! is.na(myvector))` and then `parsed <- myvector; parsed[ind] <- anytime(myvector[ind]))`

Comment: And the next release of anytime will process NA (as well as NaN and Inf) as well and just return NA.